# bootstrap offsetting without overrides

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, offset

Im new to bootstrap and have not used their grid system before. I am trying to use the full *12* grid and have one div *1-5* and one *8-12* so each div *col-lg-5*.

Im trying not to override there CSS much to keep it clean, I seem to have a problem with *float:left*. As far as i can tell from the documentation I am using the system correctly, but its not working, the second div drops to the next line.

**MY CODE**

```
 <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-5 well well-lg">
                <h2>Heading</h2>
                <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor
                    mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada
                    magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-5 col-lg-offset-7 well well-lg">
                <h2>Heading</h2>
                <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor
                    mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada
                    magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is that you have two different `.col-lg-5` divs in one row, and you added `.col-lg-offset-7` class to the second one (5 + 5 + 7 = 17). However, the offset class should be `.col-lg-offset-2` not to exceed the **12 columns** grid system.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-5 well well-lg">
        <h2>Heading</h2>
        <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor
            mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada
            magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-5 col-lg-offset-2 well well-lg">
        <h2>Heading</h2>
        <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor
            mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada
            magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here are the other examples for you to understand how the grid system works:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">.col-md-4 .col-md-offset-4</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-3">.col-md-3 .col-md-offset-3</div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-3">.col-md-3 .col-md-offset-3</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">.col-md-6 .col-md-offset-3</div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it works, ill accept the answer. I see so you off set from the previous div not from 1?

Comment: up 1 for the explanation